# Can AccessibilityService click button without opening the app

Tags: java, accessibility

Perform click event on background without opening app using accessibility service, I can perform click event while app screen in foreground but for background the resource id for button on that screen is not found

Kindly provide the solution or give anyother way to achieve this

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for an AccessibilityService to perform a click event on a button without opening the app.

An AccessibilityService can perform a click event on a button without opening the app by finding a clickable element on the screen and using the AccessibilityService API. The AccessibilityService can handle the "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" Intent and request the Manifest.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE permission to ensure that only the system can bind to it.

Here's how to implement it:

1. Identify the button you want to click and the app it belongs to.
2. Create an AccessibilityService that extends AccessibilityService.
3. In the AccessibilityService, override the onServiceConnected() method to set the service's configuration and register callbacks using registerAccessibilityButtonCallback().
4. In the onAccessibilityButtonClicked() method, find the button you want to click using the AccessibilityNodeInfo class and perform a click event on it.
5. Use the AccessibilityService to perform the click event on the button without opening the app.

**Here's an example code snippet:**

public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();

    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_ACCESSIBILITY_BUTTON;
    setServiceInfo(info);

    AccessibilityButtonController accessibilityButtonController = getAccessibilityButtonController();
    accessibilityButtonController.registerAccessibilityButtonCallback(new AccessibilityButtonController.AccessibilityButtonCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onClicked(AccessibilityButtonController controller) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = findButton("Button Name", "com.example.app");
            if (nodeInfo != null) {
                nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
            }
        }
    });
}

private AccessibilityNodeInfo findButton(String buttonName, String packageName) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = getRootInActiveWindow();
    if (nodeInfo == null) {
        return null;
    }

    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodes = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(buttonName);
    for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : nodes) {
        if (node.getPackageName().equals(packageName)) {
            return node;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

By following these steps, you can implement an AccessibilityService to perform a click event on a button without opening the app.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, can you explain how to implement this?

Comment: Edited the above answer.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but the button can be clicked only when it is visible on the screen(active), Is there possible to click button even that button screen is not visible(Background)?